# How to edit an embed?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I cannot edit an embed that is already posted, here is my code :

```js
const c = client.channels.cache.get('919237216692215829')
const m = c.messages.cache.get('919675014633095179')
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
//embed..
m.edit(embed)

console:

m.edit(embed)
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined
```

Comment: Discord.js version?

Comment: Discord.js v12 :)

Comment: It's telling you that `m` is undefined which means the `get()` is not doing what you expect

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to fix this, I'm trying to modify, adding the integer variables but it does the same, I don't understand the error ..

Comment: It means the message was not found

Answer (score 0):

Consider fetching the messages instead of retrieving from cache.

```js
const m = await c.messages.fetch('919675014633095179');
```

Comment: This should be awaited

Comment: My bad, edited. Thankyou.